# Why I can't add the class of css using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a question about my code, I am trying to make the div with the display id to be green when the result is greater than 10, it does not work except for the calculation.  if the result > 10, make the entire #display element text green. otherwise, make it red with the classes above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .highText {
      color: green;
    }

    .lowText {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(startApp);

    function startApp() {
    function doCalculation(){
      var number1 = Number($('#number1').val());
      var number2 = Number($('#number2').val());
      var result = number1 + number2;
      if(result > 10){
        $('#display').addClass('.highText');
        $('#display span').text(result);
      }
      else{
        $('#display').addClass('.lowText');
        $('#display span').text(result);
    }

    }
    $('#doIt').on('click', doCalculation);

  }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="number1" placeholder="1st number"> +
  <input type="text" id="number2" placeholder="2nd number">
  <div id="display">result--- <span></span></div>
  <button id="doIt">calculate!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify two things:

- addClass and removeClass accept only class names without dots;
- You should remove "highText" when you add "lowText" and vice versa;

Here is the working script: http://cssdeck.com/labs/v9fvdfxn